# draw not continuous line on drag mouse with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to make simple painter program so I studying OpenGL.
Today I practiced draw line with `GL_POINTS` and `GL_LINE_STRIP`. and here is some problem.
for example

[image]

I want to draw this way. but If I use `glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP)`

It looks like this image.

[image]

every line is continuous.
How to remove that lines? Is it difficult?
(anyway sorry for my English... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP)` again for each new line to separate them. If you have a list of lines like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> lines;
```

Then you can draw them like this:

```
for (auto& line : lines) {
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    for (auto& point : line) {
        glVertex2f(point.x, point.y);
    }

    glEnd(GL_LINE_STRIP);
}
```

However, you should really stop using functions like `glBegin` and use modern OpenGL functions, as taught in tutorials like:

- http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/
- http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/
- http://open.gl/
- http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html